# provide root user to a single task ansible

Tags: ansible

i have the host file

```
[controller]
1.1.1.1
2.2.2.2
3.3.3.3
```

and i set my master to be 1.1.1.1 in group_vars

```
wsrep_ip=1.1.1.1
```

Now, i need to copy a file from 1.1.1.1 to others for which i have written the task as below

```
- hosts: all
  sudo: yes
  tasks:
    - name: Sync all configuration files across db nodes
      copy: src=/etc/mysql/debian.cnf dest=/etc/mysql/debian.cnf
      when: "'{{ inventory_hostname }}' != '{{ wsrep_ip }}'"
      with_items: groups['controller']
```

how can i switch to the root user only for this task alone ? is there any way to do that . Because, other tasks are running with sudo: yes and only this is giving a permission issue

```
fatal: [2.2.2.2] => error while accessing the file /etc/mysql/debian.cnf, error was: [Errno 13] Permission denied: u'/etc/mysql/debian.cnf'
fatal: [3.3.3.3] => error while accessing the file /etc/mysql/debian.cnf, error was: [Errno 13] Permission denied: u'/etc/mysql/debian.cnf'
```

Answer (score 4):

To make a only a single task run as sudo put the `sudo: yes` within the task definition instead of the play. I.e.

```
- hosts: all
  tasks:
    - name: Sync all configuration files across db nodes
      copy: src=/etc/mysql/debian.cnf dest=/etc/mysql/debian.cnf
      when: "'{{ inventory_hostname }}' != '{{ wsrep_ip }}'"
      with_items: groups['controller']
      sudo: yes
```

A couple of notes however.

1. `become` is the new version of `sudo` in Ansible so you may as well use `become: yes` instead of `sudo` http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/become.html
2. You could probably simplify this task definition using the `delegate_to` keyword :) http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/playbooks_delegation.html#delegation

**Edit**

I just re-read your task properly and I think I can see the error in your logic.

The `copy` module is for copying files from the local (the machine running ansible) box to the box the task is currently running on. When you say `sudo: yes` on the copy task, it means try and save the file as root on the *destination* box, but won't read the file from the Ansible box as root.

You're going to need to use `delegate_to` to make it copy the file from the `wsrep_ip` box.

E.g. (Untested sorry)

```
- hosts: all
  tasks:
    - name: Sync all configuration files across db nodes
      copy: src=/etc/mysql/debian.cnf dest=/etc/mysql/debian.cnf
      delegate_to: "{{ wsrep_ip }}"
      when: "'{{ inventory_hostname }}' != '{{ wsrep_ip }}'"
      sudo: yes
```

This means delegate the `copy` action to the `wsrep_ip` box so that the `src` paramter means the source file on `wsrep_ip`, not the Ansible control machine.

Comment: but /etc/mysql/debian.cnf is owned by root. and when i run "ansible-playbook test.yml -i hosts -u ubuntu" am getting permission error

Comment: i need to copy the file as root . only then it will allow. for other users file is not even visible